# Math question please integral?

Tags: integration

What is the area of the finite region bounded by the x-axis, the curve 
y=1/sqrt(1-x^2) and the asymptotes of this curve?
The horizontal asymptote does not exist,the vertical ones are -1 and 1 so to find the surface should I just find the integral defined by -1 and 1 of 1/[sqrt(1-x^2)] and multiply it by 2?

Comment: You need to rephrase the question. It is a bit unclear. If it is a homework problem try to stay close to the statement of the problem.

Comment: The question is not as clearly put as it could be. But probably you are looking for $\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. The integral should be a familiar one.

Comment: So if I am right the question should look something like "What is the area of the finite region bounded by the $x$-axis, the curve $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$, and the asymptotes of this curve?"

Comment: yes,thank you..I edited my question,can you look at it again?

Comment: It also won't bother to hve your question written with LaTeX. You can find directions in the FAQ section.

Comment: Either (i) integrate from $0$ to $1$ and multiply by $2$ (my preference) or (ii) integrate from $-1$ to $1$ and don't multiply by anything.

Answer (score 1):

As the integrand isn't bounded in the given interval this is an improper integral:

$$\int\limits_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\lim_{a,b\to 0^+}\int\limits_{-1+a}^{1-b}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\left.\lim_{a,b\to 0}\arcsin x\right|_{-1+a}^{1-b}=\ldots$$